# Which jQueryUI handles are predefined in wordpress?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, jquery-ui

In section 4 of [this blog entry](http://www.zigpress.com/2011/04/27/jquery-ui-datepicker-in-wordpress-admin/) jQueryUI is loaded by

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker', $pluginfolder . '/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core') );
```

The first two lines indicate, that jquery UI handles are predefined. The third line loads the datepicker from a custom file whereas the datepicker seems to be onboard with concurrent Wordpress.

Since I don't want to join the cargo cult, how can I load as much jQueryUI as possible from onboard hence avoiding custum overloading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take a look at the Codex for all the [default scripts and their slugs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress).

The jQuery UI stuff is:

```
Name                           Handle                    Dependencies
```

```
jQuery UI Core                 jquery-ui-core            jquery
jQuery UI Widget               jquery-ui-widget          jquery
jQuery UI Mouse                jquery-ui-mouse           jquery
jQuery UI Accordion            jquery-ui-accordion       jquery
jQuery UI Autocomplete         jquery-ui-autocomplete    jquery
jQuery UI Slider               jquery-ui-slider          jquery
jQuery UI Tabs                 jquery-ui-tabs            jquery
jQuery UI Sortable             jquery-ui-sortable        jquery
jQuery UI Draggable            jquery-ui-draggable       jquery
jQuery UI Droppable            jquery-ui-droppable       jquery
jQuery UI Selectable           jquery-ui-selectable      jquery
jQuery UI Position             jquery-ui-position        jquery
jQuery UI Datepicker           jquery-ui-datepicker      jquery
jQuery UI Resizable            jquery-ui-resizable       jquery
jQuery UI Dialog               jquery-ui-dialog          jquery
jQuery UI Button               jquery-ui-button          jquery
jQuery UI Effects              jquery-effects-core       jquery
jQuery UI Effects - Blind      jquery-effects-blind      jquery-effects-core
jQuery UI Effects - Bounce     jquery-effects-bounce     jquery-effects-core
jQuery UI Effects - Clip       jquery-effects-clip       jquery-effects-core
jQuery UI Effects - Drop       jquery-effects-drop       jquery-effects-core
jQuery UI Effects - Explode    jquery-effects-explode    jquery-effects-core
jQuery UI Effects - Fade       jquery-effects-fade       jquery-effects-core
jQuery UI Effects - Fold       jquery-effects-fold       jquery-effects-core 
jQuery UI Effects - Highlight  jquery-effects-highlight  jquery-effects-core
jQuery UI Effects - Pulsate    jquery-effects-pulsate    jquery-effects-core
jQuery UI Effects - Scale      jquery-effects-scale      jquery-effects-core
jQuery UI Effects - Shake      jquery-effects-shake      jquery-effects-core
jQuery UI Effects - Slide      jquery-effects-slide      jquery-effects-core
jQuery UI Effects - Transfer   jquery-effects-transfer   jquery-effects-core
```